# Is a script specified by `<script>` element with `async` attribute loaded and executed in a different thread (or process) from the parser?

Tags: javascript, browser

From ***JavaScript: The Definitive Guide***:

> When the parser in a web browser parses a web page and encounters a
>   `<script>` element that has the `async` attribute set, it begins
>   downloading the script text and continues parsing the document. The
>   script will be executed as soon as possible after it has downloaded,
>   but the parser does not  stop  and  wait  for  it  to  download.

Is a script specified by `<script>` element with `async` attribute loaded and executed in a different thread (or process) from the parser?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. What difference do you think would it make?

Comment: How can the script and the parser  be executed simultaneously?

Comment: That's not what it says, it only says that it's *downloaded* simultaneously. There are many ways to achieve concurrency without multithreading, async io is one of them. Whether the parser continues to run while the script is executed is a different question - but it should not matter to you anyway.